# Wordpress & Woocommerce: Merge data before import to production

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, woocommerce

I have an issue, and quite a big one I guess.
Let me state it;

I have a website on production, running with Wordpress & Woocommerce. 
The website is running ok, get orders and new users. Website is configured with custom theme named X, and it's been like this for 2 years now.

Now we are in 2017, and I want to change my theme, and make a custom theme named Y. So I will work on it for, let's say, 2 weeks.

Here is my process:

1. Dump Prod, and set up Developement Environment (Files and DB)
2. Create a *custom rule in .htaccess* to get images from production,
   so you can empty the `/uploads` folder
3. Set up Github. Start working and developing features.

> Then after 2 weeks, my website is done. I want to put it live. ***But,
>   meh***, there were orders and new clients, so how can I pass this to
>   developement website, and then import to production?

I'm seeking for help, maybe there is a dumb thing I didn't thought about.

I've went through the Plugin WP Migrate DB Pro, useless for this.

I've heard of MergeBot, but it's still in beta, and not woocommerce friendly.

Long story short, HELP!

Thanks

Comment: orders and clients will be in separate tables which will not be impacted by your local change . is it not ? means cant you push partailly instead of the whole

Comment: As far as I know, Woocommerce is using the same tables as Wordpress, it is not creating his own tables, like other plugins

Comment: anyone has proper solution? up